# yii2 url непоняятный

Tags: yii2

у сайта появились дублирующие url следующиего вида: http://site.ru/assets/9af6b214/catalog/tovaryi
Правильно:
http://site.ru/catalog/tovaryi

Как избавиться? или запретить????? Url правила строгие! там нет ничего подобного. Откуда это могло вылезти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

почитайте про ассеты. ________________________________________ https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/structure-assets/